# Hide Banner only from Home page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this site [My Website](http://fplnepal.com)
As you can there is Google ad banner on top . 
Now I want to completely remove it form ONLY HOMEPAGE.
I inserted the google ad from

```
"Insert header and footer"
```

plugins from Wordpress as my themes do not support header widget(I would love this too) .
I want my ad to be seen else where like pages and posts but not in my Home page.
I looked for the forums and internet, They told me to try css tweak like display none, but it didnt work, as I didnt find the meta tag.

Comment: you cant you try is_front_page() or is_home() functions of wordpress

Comment: Yes I mena fornt page. Which is my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

in your home page before your google ad  is inserted write an condition as

```
if(!is_home())
{
// google  ad banner code

}
```

Comment: I pasted the code just ahead of the google ad code. Instead the code and the banner gets displayed lol

Comment: Here in other pages it {https://ibb.co/h0Jgke}
Here i pasted {https://ibb.co/nbOxQe}

Comment: <?php 

down vote
in your home page before your google ad is inserted write an condition as

if(!is_home())
{
?>

// Ad banner code

<?php } ?>

Comment: send where u have added

Comment: There are literally about 20+ php files :/

Answer (score 0):

use is_page function like this

```
if(is_page('5'))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. It's working. I have checked it. For testing purpose, you can run this code on different pages by using the console.

```
if (parent.jQuery('body.home').length > 0) {
parent.jQuery('head').append("<style>.adsbygoogle{display : none!important}</style>");
}
```

Comment: Wait where to paste this code? sample place where i inserted google ad?

Comment: No.  Just paste it in your js file

Comment: Where can i find the JS file? My site is fully made with wordpress. I had adsense ad code, and i installed the plugins called "insert header and footer" . Then i pasted the code in header area form the plugins.

Comment: There should a js file in your WordPress theme folder which one you are currently using. Paste it in your js file

Comment: or you can test it in your plugin settings where you adding the google add script. after google script add this.  
<script>if (parent.jQuery('body.home').length > 0) {
parent.jQuery('head').append("<style>.adsbygoogle{display : none!important}</style>");
}</script>

Comment: it should work. properly add  this code in js file or in your plugin where you can add js.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(!is_home())
 {
?>
// ad banner code

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Provide some explanation, so others are able to follow your intend.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the google ads code which you have inserted already and use this in footer.php file located under themes/zerif-lite/footer.php

Use this in footer.php before end of body tag

```
<?php global $post;

 if( $post->ID != 5) { ?>

      <!-- add google ad code here -->

<?php } ?>
```

or

```
<?php if( !is_home()) { ?>

      <!-- add google ad code here -->

<?php } ?>
```

**is_home()** - this is the default function in wordpress to filter only home

**$post->ID != 5** - means - your home page id is 5, so this will add the code other than homepage

Comment: I want to remove ads of only header. so why should I edit the footer ? footer ad is okay. I just want to remove top header ad ONLY from front page or homepage

Comment: Ok I got that. But How do i hide the top ad? only in homepage?